Rails callback, create a record after creating or updating an associated record
Can I, or should I, use a callback to create an associated record in Rails? Also, if either record creation or update fails will both records not be saved in the database?
The idea behind this solution is to DRY up the code.
If so, should I use after_save or something else? If I should use after_save, is the example below sufficient or do I need to raise an error or do something else?
I am aware of gems like papertrail that will do something like this but this is not the solution we need.
Example:
class Fruit < ApplicationRecord

end


class Apple < ApplicationRecord
  after_save :create_fruit
 
  def create_fruit
     Fruit.create!(item_id: self.id)
  end
end

It seems that there will be a rollback and both records will not be saved based on this answer and here. I do believe this answer may help also but still think I need to ask this question at the moment. Will my example rollback if there is an issue with either record update or creation?

The "should I" question is a lot more controversial than the "can I" question. Callbacks can make your code more succint but they can also make your code brittle, hard to debug, test and reason about and can introduce strong coupling. In this case you really don't need a callback - you just need to read the guides on associations.

You don't need a callback.
If you just setup an association between the two models you can create both at once:
class Fruit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :item, polymorphic: true
end

class Apple < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :fruit, as: :item
end

apple = Apple.new
apple.build_fruit
apple.save

This will create both in a transaction. If you want to fire the validations on Fruit you can use validates_associated:
class Apple < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :fruit, as: :item
  validates_assocatiated :item
end

Sure you could wrap this process into a callback - but just do it explicitly for now and refactor when and if you actually need it as callbacks come with their own set of drawbacks.

Every callback in Rails is wrapped within a transaction, so you are correct: if something goes wrong, all changes made within the callbacks will be rolled back.
A quick note about your code: the after_save callback is triggered both after creating a new record and after updating an existing one. I assume you don’t want to create a new fruit every time an apple is updated. In this case, you should use the after_create callback, which only runs when a new record is created.
Additionally, you can leverage Rails associations. This feature provides many useful methods, such as create_<your association name> (in your case, create_fruit), which makes it easier to manage associated records.
Here's the solution I suggest:
class Fruit < ApplicationRecord; end

class Apple < ApplicationRecord
  has_one :fruit, foreign_key: :item_id, class_name: 'Fruit'
  after_create :create_fruit, if: -> { fruit.blank? }
end

